# Using semi-colon in "You must do this: do A; and do B"

Tags: semicolons

I am not sure if I should use a semi-colon in the example sentence below.
Can somebody help me?

> To apply for your leave, first you must do the following: contact the person A
> in the HR department to get a form A; and contact the person B in the Finance
> department to get a form B.

I am not sure because in this example there are only 2 descriptions and I read somewhere that semicolon is used with three or more list items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a semicolon.

A semicolon can be used instead of a comma to separate items in a list if the items themselves have commas.  This can avoid ambiguity:

> You should: Call Mary, Mike, or Peter and get form A; and submit a blue, green, or pink form to Finance.

The semicolon might help a reader to understand that.

However it would be better if you used a bulleted list. You should use a bulleted list if the items are more than single words or short phrases.

> To apply for your leave, first you must do the following:
>
> - Contact person A in the HR department to get a form A.
> - Contact person B in the Finance department to get a form B.

Now you can make each item a sentence and the structure is much clearer than it would be if you use a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!